Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Option based portfolio insurance in practice

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)


Fitting stochastic variance distributions to index return data

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)


Heat/Diffusion Equation

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)


CVA number used by Finance Team

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)


Sharpe Ratio - my own calculation differs from Yahoo finance, Morningstar

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)


How to find optimal look back in quant trading models

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)


Opposite of Tail-Risk Hedge (Established Vocabulary)

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)


Looking for Research Paper on Creation of Currency Baskets

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)


2 stocks, no shorting vs shorting. (concrete questions, mean-variance)

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)


Non-linear Dynamical Systems and Quantitave Finance

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

